# Why is auto not a reference when its initializer is a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

I'm trying to understand why `not_a_ref` is not a reference.  I understand that I can make it a reference by `auto &`.  I dug around in the standard for awhile, but got lost and couldn't figure out where this behaviour is defined.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

std::vector<int> stuff;

std::vector<int>& get_stuff()
{
    return stuff;
}

int main()
{
    auto not_a_ref = get_stuff();

    if( std::is_reference<decltype(not_a_ref)>::value )
        std::cout << "is_reference true" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "is_reference false" << std::endl;

    if( &not_a_ref != &stuff )
        std::cout << "definately not a reference" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be quite annoying if it worked they way you thought it would.  It would make `auto` far less useful, because adding a reference is easy, but removing one is a pain.

Comment: I'm by no means suggesting it should be any other way than it is - just trying to understand how this behavior is specified in the standard.  Its part of my personal goal of being able to figure this sort of thing out by just reading the standard - but I got stuck.

Comment: [Here's the paper.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1984.pdf)  I don't feel like looking in the standard, so I just googled that.  The first page has an example of a function returning a reference to a float, and the type is deduced to float.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=219). Especially the part titled `Reference Types, CV qualifiers and Storage Specifiers`, it gives a very good reason why you need to be explicit when you want a reference.

Comment: The C++11 standard literally refers you to template argument deduction (as in DeadMG's answer below), see section 7.1.6.4/6 for details. And, the template argument deduction rules are in section 14.8.2.1, but the list of rules is a bit long.

Comment: @Zac - Best way to learn how to refer to the standard is to answer questions from others using it as a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From C++11 draft, 7.1.6.4 (`auto` specifier) paragraph 6:

> The type deduced for the variable d is then the deduced A determined using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1).

And from 14.8.2.1 (*Deducing template arguments from a function call*) paragraph 3:

> If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.

So the reference is just ignored for the type deduction of `auto`.

Note how this rule is different from that of `decltype`.

**UPDATE**: Please see my comment below, as I think 14.8.2.1 paragraph 3 does not apply.

Comment: Now, I have to correct myself... In 14.8.2.1, `P` is the type of the template parameter type (that is `auto`) while `A` is the type of the expression used for deduction. However, the type of an expression is never a reference, so the main fact remains that an `auto x` variable will never be a reference.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at template argument deduction. `auto x = stuff;` is quite equivalent to `template<typename T> void f(T x) {} f(stuff);` inso far as the type of `x`.

Answer (score -1):

According to the C++11 standard, auto counts as a simple-type-specifier [7.1.6.2], therefore the same rules apply to it as to other simple-type-specifiers. This means that declaring references with auto is no different from anything else.

This means next line :

```
auto not_a_ref = get_stuff();
```

is going to be the same as :

```
std::vector<int> not_a_ref = get_stuff();
```